# Basic Probability Question - Misunderstanding

Tags: probability

I think I am misunderstanding or reading too much into this probability question:

[image]

I know what it wants me to do, but I am struggling to get my head around how the context is possible. It tells me the chance of raining is either 0.8 or 0.6, but then all of a sudden, there is a 70% chance of raining. How is this not contradictory information?

Secondly, why is it an 'estimate' - is a probability not an 'estimate' in the first place?

Comment: First, the difference in phrasing of "estimate" vs "probability" here is irrelevant.  Second, the 70% chance it rains on monday is not contradictory to what you had heard already with the other probabilities.  Imagine for instance that this was friday that the forecaster was making this prediction and he was making this prediction several days in advance.

Comment: It doesn't matter to us really *how* he came up with his probability for monday.  So long as we believe his method for figuring that out, we can then use our givens to work out our belief about wednesday.  This can be done trivially with a tree diagram.

Answer (score 1):

We can take it in cases. Either it will rain on Monday, or it will not. Either it will rain on Tuesday, or it will not.

The probability that it rains Monday is given; it's $7/10$. The probability that it does not rain on Monday is the complement, $1 - 7/10 = 3/10$.

The probability that it rains Tuesday is the probability that it rains Monday times the probability that it rains Tuesday *given* that it rains Monday, plus the probability that it doesn't rain Monday times the probability that it rains Tuesday *given* that it doesn't rain Monday (Bayes). This is $(4/5) (7/10) + (3/5) (3/10)= 28/50 + 9/50 = 37/50$. The probability that it doesn't rain Tuesday is the complement, $1 - 37/50 = 13/50$.

Applying the same logic for Wednesday, we find the desired probability is

$$(4/5) (37/50) + (3/5) (13/50) = 148/250 + 39/250 = 187/250$$

Answer (score 0):

K. Jiang worked out the answer to the stated problem, but I think this was not your question in the first place (you write "I know what it wants me to do, but ..."). So I will give it another try:

- I agree with you that the formulation would be better without the word "estimate", because the conditions are stated as exact facts (the probability is *exactly* 0.8, if ... etc.). In practice, however, all probabilities are estimates, since we can never know the true probabilities exactly. I would not read too much into it, though. Also, in statistics, one often has to estimate probabilites, so there really is no contradiction of any kind. For example, if you have a (possibly unfair) coin, you might want to figure out the probability of it giving "heads". You might do this by tossing it 1000 times, the corresponding ratio will then give you an *estimate* of that probability.
- The fact that the initial raining probability (on Monday) is 0.7 does not contradict the other statements. The statements are basically of the form "If your *only* information is, that it rains on one day, then the probability is ...". However, there may be additional sources of information. Say, it did not rain on Sunday in your town, but there was a storm in a town nearby. Maybe this additional information "updates" your probability (estimate) to 0.7. Or another scenario, it is Sunday 3 p.m. and it has not rained *so far*, but it still may. This does not mean that there will be no rain on Sunday (so you cannot say that the Monday-rain-probability is 0.6), so maybe the weather prediction model you use gives you the probability 0.7, and, the longer you wait (without rain), the closer it gets to 0.6 and reaches 0.6 at midnight (at which point you are certain that there was no rain on Sunday).

Hope this helps

*Comment:* As so often with such "academic" exercises there are some hidden assumptions involved, in this case the "Markov property", which says (roughly) that the probability for rain on the next day depends only on the current day and not on the full history of rain. Imagine you live in a place where it is extremely unlikely that it does not rain for three days in a row. Then the conditional probabilities of 0.6 and 0.8 might still be correct, while knowing that it does not rain on Monday and Tuesday would tell you that it will rain on Wednesday with a very high probability, so the classical "tree diagram computation" would give you a wrong result (it is only correct under the stated assumption). Also, I am not a fan of the formulation "if ... then the probability is ..." for conditional probabilities and prefer to replace "if" by "given that", which better reflects the probabilistic thinking and conditioning process.